# Linux zip -i recursively

Tags: linux, terminal, zip

I'm trying to recursively include some folders in my zip, using a terminal command, for example, let's say that I have this:

```
/folder1/
/folder1/folder2
/folder3/
/file1
/file2
```

I want my zip file to include folder1 content and its subdirectories contents, and the files in the root directory (file1 and file2)

Currently I have this command:

```
 zip -r myzip.zip ./ -i folder1/* -i ./*
```

But the resulting zip doesn't includes folder2

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
zip -r myzip.zip . -i folder1/\* *
```

Notes on OP:

- The `*` after `folder1/` must be escaped.
- The final `*` is substituted by the shell with the files in the root folder (`.`) *nonrecursively*, meaning not including `folder3`. The syntax `-i ./\*` would pick up these files *recursively*, including `folder3`.